# Bazel build failed : Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/text_format.h': No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules

I encountered a really odd issue when using bazel with protobuf.

The compiler complain `C:\users\liuzichao\_bazel_liuzichao\in4szefe\execroot\__main__\renderer/util.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/text_format.h': No such file or directory`

I have added rules_proto in my `WORKDSPACE`

```
http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
    sha256 = "e017528fd1c91c5a33f15493e3a398181a9e821a804eb7ff5acdd1d2d6c2b18d",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-4.0.0-3.20.0",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0-3.20.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()
```

Then I added `@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf` to my util cc_library

```
cc_library(
  name = "util",
  srcs = [
    "util.h",
    "util.cc",
  ],
  deps = [
    "//base:debug",
    "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf",
    "@glm",
  ],
)
```

But compiler cannot find `<google/protobuf/text_format.h>` in util.h

```
#pragma once

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <google/protobuf/text_format.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "base/debug.h"
```

Could someone can help me to fix compile error? I have stucked here for a couple of days.
The rules_proto generated protobuf rule as follow which seems all right.

```
cc_library(
    name = "protobuf",
    srcs = [
        # AUTOGEN(protobuf_srcs)
        "src/google/protobuf/any.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/api.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/map_field.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/message.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/service.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/struct.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/type.pb.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/default_value_objectwriter.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/error_listener.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_escaping.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_objectwriter.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info_test_helper.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc",
        "src/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(["src/**/*.h", "src/**/*.inc"]),
    copts = COPTS,
    includes = ["src/"],
    linkopts = LINK_OPTS,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":protobuf_lite"] + PROTOBUF_DEPS,
)
```

Comment: I have the same problem, can't find a way to solve it

Comment: Came across this question while encountering the same problem and found a solution in this github issue: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/12947 Changing the output base directory to a very short path solved it for me. Maybe that's helpful for others comming here as well...